# Can not Autowire bean in Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

I am trying to unit test a Controller Class with Junit. However, when I try to autowire my PlayerRepository interface, which extends crudRepository, it gives this error:

> 2018-12-06 21:59:39.530 ERROR 8780 --- [           main]
>   o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
>   allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@78e117e3]
>   to prepare test instance
>   [edu.ceng.gameproject.player.PlayerControllerTest@4f704591]

(I did not put the entire error since it is very long.)

and it also says:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'edu.ceng.gameproject.player.PlayerRepository'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

By the way, I can do the autowire in my controller to make changes on database. It just does not work in testing. Here is my code:

Controller Class:

```
@Controller    // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/Player") // This means URL's start with /Player 
(after Application path)

public class PlayerController {

 @Autowired 
 private PlayerRepository playerRepository;
}
```

Here is the PlayerRepsitory interface:

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends CrudRepository<Player, String> {


}
```

Abstract test class where I do the autowiring :

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)

 @WebAppConfiguration
 public abstract class GameProjectBackEndApplicationTests {

 protected MockMvc mvc;

 @Autowired
 WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

 @Autowired
 PlayerRepository playerRepository;


 protected void setUp() {
     mvc = 
  MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
 }

}
```

PlayerControllerTest class where I use the autowired playerRepository:

```
public class PlayerControllerTest extends GameProjectBackEndApplicationTests 
{

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getUsersList_withOk() throws Exception {
        String uri = "/Player/all";

        // Create user in the database
        Player createdUser = playerRepository.save(new Player("testUser", 
"testPassword"));

        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).andReturn();

        // check if status is 200 - OK
        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        assertEquals(200, status);

        String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        Player[] playerList = super.mapFromJson(content, Player[].class);

        // check if list has actually any user
        assertTrue(playerList.length > 0);


        // check returned list has user that we created
        boolean contains = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
            if 
              (createdUser.getUsername().equals(playerList[i].getUsername())
                    && 
    createdUser.getPasswd().equals(playerList[i].getPasswd())) {
                contains = true;
            }
        }
        // assert there is a user that we created
        assertTrue(contains);
        //delete created user
        playerRepository.deleteById(createdUser.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did your try to add @DataJpaTest on your TestClass?

Comment: tried but didn't work.

Comment: Use `@MockBean` to inject required dependencies.

Comment: How do I supposed to use @MockBean, can you be more clear ?

Comment: What are the relative packages?  IF the PlayerControllerTest is in a package that isn't at or above the package where your @Controller is defined, then Spring's default auto-detection won't find your controller.  In this case you need to specifically tell Spring which packages to include in the scan, easily done via annotations.  If that's not the issue, I've a second idea.

Comment: they are at the same package.

Comment: Basically you declare `PlayerRepository` in your test annotated with `@MockBean`. It will be injected inside your controller. Also you should mock all the method calls used from the repository. In other words use `@MockBean` instead `@Autowired` for `PlayerRepository playerRepository` in your test class.

Comment: I just replaced Autowired with MockBean and changed the RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) annotation as RunWith(SpringRunner.class) now it seems to solve the issue, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, use `@MockBean` to inject a mock for every dependency needed in your controller. Your test class will look like this.

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)

 @WebAppConfiguration
 public class GameProjectBackEndApplicationTests {

     private MockMvc mvc;

     @Autowired
     private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

     @MockBean
     private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
         mvc = 
         MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

         // Mock calls to PlayerRepository
         // Mockito.when(playerRepository.getEntries(1)).thenReturn(myList);
     }

     @Test
     public void myTest() {
      ....
     }

}
```

Also, I don't really recommend using inheritance for your tests. It is better to have everything in one place.